# interface listener becomes null in fragment even after initialization

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have fragment listener implemented in activity and im initializing it in onAttach() method. In fragment i have been making asynchronous calls and also starting another activity for result. After onActivityResult is called and process the request code then im calling listener implementation in the activity but listener throws NPE always. im very confused to know how the listener variable becomes null after it get results from another activity.
any idea on how its happening?

```
class ReviewFragment extends Fragment {
private OnReviewContinueButtonClickListener mListener;
/* many other variables */

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_INSTAMOJO_PAYMENT) {
            mListener.onContinueButtonClick(mailId);
            showSuccessScreen(mailId);
        }
        if (requestCode == PaytmWalletManager.REQUEST_CODE_REGISTER_PAYTM_WALLET || requestCode == PaytmWalletManager.REQUEST_CODE_ADD_MONEY) {
            initiatePaytmPayment();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnReviewContinueButtonClickListener) {
        mListener = (OnReviewContinueButtonClickListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnReviewContinueButtonClickListener");
    }

}
 /* im calling this function middle of fragment from asynchronous network call onsuccess method without runonuithread() */
 private void pay(JSONObject paymentObject) throws JSONException {

    Intent payment = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), WebviewActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(3);
    bundle.putString(WebviewActivity.TITLE, "Make Payment");
    startActivityForResult(payment, REQUEST_CODE_INSTAMOJO_PAYMENT);
    hideProgressDialog();

}

 // on calling this method from asynchronous network result onSuccess()
 private void registerForFree(String orderId, String paymentId) {
    AppEventTracker.logEvent("register for free clicked", "success", "Flight Booking");

    getApp().getAccountManager().registerFreeTicketPatchCall(orderId, paymentId, getFreeTicketRegisterBody(), new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void success(JsonElement jsonElement, Response response) {
            if (getActivity() == null) return;
            hideProgressDialog();
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mListener.onContinueButtonClick(mailId); // mlistener is null here even though it has been initialized on onAttach(). 
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            if (getActivity() == null) return;
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    if (showErrorDialog) {
                        showErrorDialog = false;
                        showPriceChangeDiaglog("Error in payment generation");
                    }
                    AppEventTracker.logEvent("register for free clicked", "failure", "Explara buy Ticket");


        }
    });
}
```

Activity which implements above fragment is

```
class booking extends Activity implements ReviewFragment.OnReviewContinueButtonClickListener{

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PaytmWalletManager.REQUEST_CODE_REGISTER_PAYTM_WALLET || requestCode == PaytmWalletManager.REQUEST_CODE_ADD_MONEY) {
            ReviewItineraryFragment fragment = (ReviewItineraryFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ReviewItinerary");
            fragment.initiatePaytmPayment();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onContinueButtonClick(String mail) {
        showSuccessScreen(mail);
}

private void showSuccessScreen(String mail) {
    if (this != null && !this.isFinishing()) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Order Confirmation");
        FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        String email = mail;
        String type = "Order";
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, PaymentSuccess.newInstance(email, type));
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: it's better if you provide ur code

Comment: is it problem if its not called from main thread?